# Executing SQL query with variable number of named parameters in Golang

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go

So I have this PostgreSQL function, which takes variable number of named arguments and returns list of corresponding items:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION read_user(
  _id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
  _phone VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  _type VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  _last VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  _first VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
) 
RETURNS setof T_USERS
AS $$ 
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT * FROM T_USERS
  WHERE ( id = _id OR _id IS NULL )
    AND ( phone = _phone OR _phone IS NULL )
    AND ( type = _type OR _type IS NULL )
    AND ( last = _last OR _last IS NULL )
    AND ( first = _first OR _first IS NULL );
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
      RAISE WARNING 'Transaction failed and was rolled back';
      RAISE NOTICE '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So I can run polymorphic queries like these:

```
SELECT read_user(_id := 2);
SELECT read_user(_first := 'John', _last := 'Doe');
```

In Golang I can make something like:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT read_user(_id = ?)")
```

But how can I do the same, but with variable amount of `read_user` arguments? I'm using `pq` driver https://github.com/lib/pq.

Comment: What db driver are you using to talk to postgres?

Comment: @mkopriva [link](http://github.com/lib/pq) pq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct your one statement by enumerating **all** the parameters with their placeholders and then you could pass `nil` explicitly where you don't have the parameter value.

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT read_user(_id := $1, _phone := $2, _type := $3, _last := $4, _first := $5)")
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
stmt.Query(2, nil, nil, nil, nil) // result should be equivalent to `SELECT read_user(_id := 2)`
stmt.Query(nil, nil, nil, "Doe", "John") // result should be equivalent to `SELECT read_user(_first := 'John', _last := 'Doe')`
```

And if you want to have named parameters in Go as well, you can create a struct type to represent the parameters and a wrapper func that'll map that parameter type's fields into the query:

```
type readUserParams struct {
    Id    interface{}
    Phone interface{}
    Type  interface{}
    Last  interface{}
    First interface{}
}

func readUser(p *readUserParams) {
    stmt.Query(p.Id, p.Phone, p.Type, p.Last, p.First)
    // ...
}

readUser(&readUserParams{Id: 2})
readUser(&readUserParams{First: "John", Last:"Doe"})
```

Comment: It works, but could you explain how `nil` is translated to named parameter in postgres? I expected postgres throw some kind of error considering assigning parameter to type, which is not expected.

Comment: I believe `nil` gets translated into `NULL` and calling the postgres function like this `SELECT read_user(_id := 2, _phone := NULL, _type := NULL...)` is valid.

Comment: This solution also works with the snowflake implementation of go :) https://godoc.org/github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake

Comment: @Pat - Your comment resolved my issue after 7 hours. Thanks.